# How to dynamize cucumber value and pass that into the login page

Tags: angularjs, angular, cucumber

How to dynamize cucumber value and pass that into the login page, for example:

If I use Adam in the cucumber scenario then it should automatically use adam login details and other information and if i use another name it should use that person's information. So i do not have to manually enter it in every step defination. How Can i achieve it?

```
Scenario: Add an item to shopping bag to place the order using mastercard
        Given that "Adam" is logged in to his account
         When he searches and adds an item from "men" section to his shopping bag
         Then he can place the order


export class LoginUser implements Task {

  static called(name: string): LoginUser {
    return new LoginUser(name);
}

  performAs(actor: PerformsTasks): PromiseLike<void> {
    return actor.attemptsTo(
      Click.on(homePageElementsMap.lnk_login),
      Enter.theValue('test@test.com').into(loginPageElementsMap.txt_login_email),
      Enter.theValue('password111').into(loginPageElementsMap.txt_login_pwd),
      Click.on(loginPageElementsMap.btn_login)
    );
  }

  constructor(private name: string) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: this is a java answer, I misread the tag. I am sure you can something similar for js.

For our tests we have a variety of users as well and we use a java class with userdata for this, set up as maps.
 We pass the value to a static method `public Map<String, String> getUserData(String username)` which contains a switch for the variety of users we have, each user is given a map of data we want to use in the tests. The users each have a private Map in the class containing login information.

Of course, there are more scalable ways, this one just gives us the flexibility of a single public `getUserData(userName)` and behind this we can do with the storage whatever we want.

Short answer: static java code containing user information for a variety of usernames.

Answer (score -1):

Is this the only way to do it? - http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html

Comment: This is supposed to be an edit to the original question not an answer to it.